# Wrong values in Dunnett post-hoc test

Tags: r, anova

I can't get the same results in R as in GraphPad Prism for repeated measures anova.

The experiment was a stimulation time course, so I have as DV=response and as factor "time" within groups, also I add a factor sample for each experiment

```
data <- read.csv("http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4828275/datos.csv")
options(contrasts=c("contr.sum","contr.poly"))

## Convert variables to factor
data <- within(data, {
sample <- factor(sample)
time <- factor(time)
})
aov <- aov(response~time+sample, data=data)
summary(glht(aov, linfct=mcp(time="Dunnett")))

     Simultaneous Tests for General Linear Hypotheses

Multiple Comparisons of Means: Dunnett Contrasts


Fit: lme.formula(fixed = response ~ time, data = data, random = ~1 | 
sample)

Linear Hypotheses:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
2 - 0 == 0    1.1789     2.0800   0.567        1
5 - 0 == 0    1.2966     2.0800   0.623        1
10 - 0 == 0   1.0555     2.0800   0.507        1
15 - 0 == 0   0.4317     2.0800   0.208        1
30 - 0 == 0   0.2148     2.0800   0.103        1
(Adjusted p values reported -- bonferroni method)
```

For repeated measures I have this code

```
aov.repeated <- ezANOVA(
  data
  , dv = .(response)
  , wid = .(time)
  , within = .(sample)
  , type = 1
  , return_aov = TRUE
)$aov
```

The GraphPad Prism results for the same data was

```
Table Analyzed  Data 1              

Repeated Measures ANOVA                 
  P value   0.0415              
  P value summary   *               
  Are means signif. different? (P < 0.05)   Yes             
  Number of groups  6               
  F 2.863               
  R square  0.4172              

 Was the pairing significantly effective?                   
  R square  0.1980              
  F 2.119               
  P value   0.1162              
  P value summary   ns              
  Is there significant matching? (P < 0.05) No              

ANOVA Table SS  df  MS      
  Treatment (between columns)   130.6   5   26.12       
  Individual (between rows) 77.30   4   19.32       
  Residual (random) 182.4   20  9.121       
  Total 390.3   29          

Dunnett's Multiple Comparison Test  Mean Diff.  q   Significant? P < 0.05?  Summary 95% CI of diff
  0 vs 2    -2.861  1.498   No  ns  -8.085 to 2.362
  0 vs 5    -5.777  3.024   Yes *   -11.00 to -0.5531
  0 vs 10   -6.009  3.146   Yes *   -11.23 to -0.7855
  0 vs 15   -4.621  2.419   No  ns  -9.844 to 0.6029
  0 vs 30   -2.581  1.351   No  ns  -7.805 to 2.642
```

How can I get the same results as above in R?
Is there a way to get Dunnett's Multiple Comparison Test in aov.repeated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All I have to go by are the labels in your .csv file, but it looks to me like you set the problem up incorrectly in Prism. I transposed your data so each row in Prism is one matched sample. So the data entry looks like this:

[image]

Now the results (from [GraphPad Prism](http://www.graphpad.com/prism) 5.04) match the results you showed from R. The differences between means match, and the q values in Prism match the z values in R:

[image]

The problem is you had told Prism, essentially, that all the values collected at one time point were matched. By transposing, I am telling Prism that all the values from one sample (at multiple time points) were matched. If you choose one-way ANOVA in Prism, and specify repeated measures, it assumes that all values in one row are matched (not that all values in one column are matched).

[Download the Prism file.](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/859/RM%20Anova.pzf)

Comment: Thank you so much, I've got an error when importing data into R corrected with 
`time <- c(rep(0,5), rep(2,5), rep(5,5), rep(10,5), rep(15,5), rep(30,5));
sample <- c(rep(1:5, 6))` so the R transposed table was bad; now I've got the same results.